# SQL запрос с условием (неравно)

Tags: php, mysql, алгоритм, mysqli

Есть код:

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tb_users
WHERE (name LIKE '%$user%' OR username LIKE '%$user%')
AND user_id != (SELECT to_id FROM tb_friends WHERE from_id =1));
```

Хочу найти пользователей похожих на переменную `$user` и чтобы его **user_id** не был равен **1**. Явно что часть кода после **AND** работает неправильно. Как мне составить код чтоб он работал правильно, то есть как мне правильно составить код с условием чтобы **user_id** не был равен **1**

Comment: Замените подзапрос на 1?

Comment: `AND user_id != 1` не?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так (всё гениальное просто):

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tb_users
WHERE (name LIKE '%$user%' OR username LIKE '%$user%')
AND user_id != 1");
```